# Как можно скормить в С# подобное значение?

Tags: c#

Как скормить такое значение: `{"reg":"date","univer":"","name":""}`?

```
 request.AddParam("listing" , "{"reg":"date","univer":"","name":""}");
```

пробовал слешами но не получилась не чего, помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему...

Comment: погуглите по запросу *экранирование кавычек c#*, или *C# quotes escape*

Comment: А как именно вы пробовали со слешами? Покажите.

Comment: request.AddParam("listing" , @"{""reg"":""date"",""univer"":"""",""name"":""""}");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Заэкранируйте кавычки:

```
request.AddParam("listing", "{\"reg\":\"date\",\"univer\":\"\",\"name\":\"\"}");
```

Или поставьте @ перед строкой и замените каждую кавычку на две:

```
request.AddParam("listing", @"{""reg"":""date"",""univer"":"""",""name"":""""}");
```

Answer (score 9):

Я конечно не против написания объекта Json вручную, но я за сериализацию, дабы избежать появления разного рода ошибок, так что как то так:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...

public class RequestListingModel
{
    [JsonProperty("reg")]
    public DateTime Reg {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("univer")]
    public string Univer {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

var jString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new RequestListingModel{
    Reg = DateTime.Now,
    Univer = "МГУ",
    Name = "Петя Иванов"
});
request.AddParam("listing" , jString);
```